# copy assets from one of the package from node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, relative-path, angular-cli-v9

I have one requirement where I am installing @PDFTron package. Along with the import I have reference the path inside .ts file,for that the files should be in the assets.
I am trying to copy files from glob but its working.
Can anybody help me in this issue.?
code is as below.

**angular.json**

```
"assets": [{
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "../node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer",
              "output": "src/assets"
            },"src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
```

**app.component.ts**

```
WebViewer(
      {
        path: "../assets/lib/webviewer/public"
    }).then(...)
```

Its not copying files.Please whats the issue in the code of angular.json

Comment: If you scaffolded your app with the Angular CLI then your `angular.json` file should be on the same level as your `node_modules` folder. Have you tried changing your `input` path to just `"node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer"`?

Comment: Yes they are on same level.I tried with "node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer".

"assets": [{
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer",
              "output": "src/assets"
            },"src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],

hard luck it didn't work.

Comment: Its working now.I misunderstood this configuration.It will work on build drop.
and there also 
input : is relative to the workspace root.
output is relative to outDir (dist/project-name default).
So I used like

"assets": [{
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer",
              "output": "/assets/lib"
            },"src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],